# How to check format

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, curated-data

I am having troubles with the following data:

```
slavelist = ResourceData["New Orleans Slave Sales 1856-1861"]
```

I want to select all slaves with:

```
SellersStateOfOrigin == Alabama,United States
```

But I don't get what's the format of it. I tried the following :

`Select[slavelist, #SellersStateOfOrigin == "Alabama,United States" &]` but it won't work...

can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select[slavelist, #SellersStateOfOrigin == 
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Alabama", "UnitedStates"}] &]
```